# Regular expression help to skip first occurrence of a special character while allowing for later special chars but no whitespace

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm looking for words starting with a hashtag: `"#yolo"`

My regex for this was very simple: `/#\w+/`

This worked fine until I hit words that ended with a question mark: `"#yolo?"`.

I updated my regex to allow for words and any non whitespace character as well: `/#[\w\S]*/`.

The problem is I sometimes need to pull a match from a word starting with two '#' characters, up until whitespace, that may contain a special character in it or at the end of the word (which I need to capture).

Example:
`"##yolo?"`
And I would like to end up with:
`"#yolo?"`

Note: the regular expressions are for Ruby.

P.S. I'm testing these out here: http://rubular.com/

Comment: Put a # inside the square braces

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
#[^#\s]+
```

`\w` is a subset of `^\s` (i.e. `\S`) so you don't need both. Also, I assume you don't want any more `#`s in the match, so we use `[^#\s]` which negates both whitespace and `#` characters.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would work

```
#(#?[\S]+)
```